# safe, fast CFLAGS for mex functions in matlab

Tags: c, gcc, matlab, mex

I am converting a number of low-level operations from native matlab code into C/mex code, with great speedups. (These low-level operations can be done vectorized in .m code, but I think I get memory hits b/c of large data. whatever.)  I have noticed that compiling the mex code with different CFLAGS can cause mild improvements. For example `CFLAGS = -O3 -ffast-math` does indeed give some speedups, at the cost of mild numerical inaccuracy.

My question: what are the "best" CFLAGS to use, without incurring too many other side effects? It seems that, at the very least that
`CFLAGS =  -O3 -fno-math-errno -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -fno-trapping-math -fno-signaling-nans` are all OK. I'm not sure about `-funroll-loops`.

also, how would you optimize the set of CFLAGS used, semi-automatically, without going nuts?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the target CPU...or are at least willing to guarantee a "minimum" CPU...you should definitely look into `-mcpu` and `-march`.

The performance gain can be significant.

Comment: I like this in principle, but have not been able to properly test it yet. will do..

Answer (score 1):

Whatever ATLAS uses on your machine (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) is probably a good starting point.  I don't know that ATLAS automatically optimizes specific compiler flags, but the developers have probably spent a fair amount of time doing so by hand.